# How do I make an element collapse horizontally and then disappear?

Tags: jquery

I've been looking at the documentation for jQuery's `hide()` command, but can't figure out how to make an element disappear by having its width shrink to zero. The default easing shrinks both height and width at the same time, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv').animate({
    'width': 0
}, 2000, 'linear');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HqELS/2

You won't need to hide it as it's already *invisible* due to width = 0.

Comment: Ah, so that's what it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#box').animate({width: "toggle" });
```

or

```
$('#box').animate({width: 0 });
```

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/oSEGeYam/1/edit)**